# Why is LastModifiedDate not listed as a standard field in the UI?

Tags: leads, standard-objects

What's wrong with my Lead object that it has no `LastModifiedDate`?

[image: lead]

I can't add it to any view or anything like that. What's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a system generated date that is not listed in the standard field list.  You will also notice that Created Date is not listed there.  These field still exist.  You can confirm by doing a simple query like below in Apex Anonymous

```
Lead l = [Select Id, Name, CreatedDate, CreatedDate, LastModifiedDate From Lead limit 1];
system.debug('Created On : ' + l.CreatedDate);
system.debug('Last Modified On : ' + l.LastModifiedDate);
```

Comment: You could also use describes. Still +1 but for the vote cap.

Comment: Do I then have to make a surrogate field to display the date in the lead detail view with a formula or something?

Comment: No, its not exactly intuitive, but in the UI, on the page layout, the Created By field shows you not only who created it, but also when.  Same goes for the Last Modified By field.  It shows both who and when.

Comment: Ah, thank-you. Not intuitive is right.